# set label size as big as QPixmap image

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I have an label that displays an image, however the image is cut off since its size is bigger than the label, I have tried `self.logo_buttons.SetScaledContents(True)`but this only resizes my image to fit in the label.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.logo_button = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.logo_button.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('image.png'))
        self.logo_button.setScaledContents(True)


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = GUI()

    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


window()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is adjust the size of the QLabel using adjustSize():

```
self.logo_button = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
self.logo_button.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('image.png'))
self.logo_button.adjustSize()
```